# Tensorflow-GPU Eager Execution: Batch Normalization extremely slow and decreases Volatile GPU-Util

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently getting used to the eager execution mode in Tensorflow. While working with my model and trying to optimize the code I found that the use of Batch Normalization layers dramatically reduces the average Volatile GPU-Utilization and also leads to an (sometimes drastic) increase in time needed per iteration (system information at bottom of this post).

To give a concrete example: I used the Tensorflow MNIST-GAN example for eager mode (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/gan/mnist.py) for my tests, after I originally observed this behavior in my own code / model. If I run the example as is (i.e. without Batch Normalization) I have a Volatile GPU-Util of 55-60% and 100 batches take around 2.8-3.0 seconds.

If I add Batch Norm (BN) layers to the discriminator this decreases the Volatile GPU-Util (monitored via nvidia-smi -l 1), especially if I add BN to the first fully connected layer of the discriminator. This is how I updated the code (only the Discriminator was updated, the rest stays as in the original example):

```
class Discriminator(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, data_format):
    """Creates a model for discriminating between real and generated digits.
    """
    super(Discriminator, self).__init__(name='')
    if data_format == 'channels_first':
      self._input_shape = [-1, 1, 28, 28]
      bn_axis = 1
    else:
      assert data_format == 'channels_last'
      self._input_shape = [-1, 28, 28, 1]
      bn_axis = 3
    self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(
        64, 5, padding='SAME', data_format=data_format, activation=None)
    self.conv1_bn = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis)
    self.pool1 = layers.AveragePooling2D(2, 2, data_format=data_format)

    self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(
        128, 5, data_format=data_format, activation=None)
    self.conv2_bn = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis)
    self.pool2 = layers.AveragePooling2D(2, 2, data_format=data_format)
    self.flatten = layers.Flatten()

    self.fc1 = layers.Dense(1024, activation=None)
    self.fc1_bn = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=1)

    self.fc2 = layers.Dense(1, activation=None)

  def call(self, inputs, training=True):
    """Return two logits per image estimating input authenticity.
    """
    x = tf.reshape(inputs, self._input_shape)
    x = self.conv1(x)
    x = self.pool1(x)
    x = self.conv1_bn(x, training=training)
    x = tf.tanh(x)

    x = self.conv2(x)
    x = self.pool2(x)
    x = self.conv2_bn(x, training=training)
    x = tf.tanh(x)
    x = self.flatten(x)

    x = self.fc1(x)
    x = self.fc1_bn(x, training=training)
    x = tf.tanh(x)

    x = self.fc2(x)

    return x
```

Now, if I run this code the Volatile GPU-Util drops to only 37-42% and 100 batches now take 4.6-4.8 seconds. This seems to be mostly influenced by BN on the fully connected layer. If I run BN only on the conv layers the GPU-Util only drops to about 55-60% (3.0-3.2 seconds for 100 batches).

I have never observed this behavior when I run TF in Graph Mode. I guess this happens sometime during the calculation of the moving average/moving variance, as the effect on GPU-Util is practically gone if I set the training parameter to "False".

Is there a reason why BN affects the performance this much in Eager Mode? Does some of the computation get moved to the CPU? Is there a way around this, i.e. can I use BN in eager mode without a decrease in GPU-Util? Or am I simply doing something wrong here?

System information:

- **OS Platform and Distribution**: Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: installed from source with pip
- **TensorFlow version**: v1.8.0-0-g93bc2e2072
- **Python version**: 2.7.12
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 9.0 / 7.0
- **GPU model and memory**: GeForce GTX 1080 (but also tested on a GTX 1050Ti with the same behavior)